# Empty ListView When using Cursor

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-contentprovider, simplecursoradapter

I am trying to fill the ListView in my fragment, but even though the Cursor is not empty as I have found out using the log cat, the ListView is still empty. I have tried using a Cursor Loader but that didn't help. The cursor is being loaded from a content provider Here is my code:

```
public class WisdomProverbsNormalFragment extends SherlockListFragment
    implements ShowcaseView.OnShowcaseEventListener {
Context mContext;

int i;

String TAG = "#Wisdom";
boolean showAds = true;

ShowcaseView sv;
AdView adView;

static final String KEY_ITEM = "tweet";
static final String KEY_PROVERB = "proverb";

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_hastag_wisdom,
            container, false);

    mContext = getSherlockActivity();


    if (haveNetworkConnection() != true) {
        // Ask for internet connection
        Context context = getActivity();
        LayoutInflater inflaterToast = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        View toastRoot = inflaterToast.inflate(
                R.layout.toast_layout_connection, null);

        Toast toast = new Toast(context);

        toast.setView(toastRoot);

        toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    } else {
        // Has connection; start service
    getSherlockActivity().startService(
                new Intent(mContext, GetTweetsService.class));
    }

    fillData();
    return rootView;
}

public void fillData() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Filling");
    String[] projection = { WisdomDB.ID, WisdomDB.PROVERB_TITLE };
    Cursor proverbs = getSherlockActivity().managedQuery(
            ProverbProvider.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null); 

    String[] from = new String[] { WisdomDB.PROVERB_TITLE };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.textView1 };

    // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
    SimpleCursorAdapter dbAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(mContext,
            R.layout.row, proverbs, from, to);

    setListAdapter(dbAdapter);

    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(dbAdapter.getCount()));

}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("TAG", "onViewCreated");
    fillData();
}
  }
```

Comment: try to fetch data using cursor after checking its count is > 0 or not

Comment: What proverbs.getCount shows

Comment: @Pankaj its 217.@Piyush how would I do that?

Comment: can you show setListAdapter(dbAdapter) methode in your code